# Mutual Information between dataset and output of algorithm

Tags: probability, information-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to understand how the Mutual Information behaves when I have a sequence of iid samples $X^n$, where each $X$ takes values in an alphabet $\mathcal{X}$ and I have an algorithm $\mathcal{A}:\mathcal{X}^n\to \mathcal{Y}$. I am not posing any constraint on $\mathcal{A}$, but I prefer to think about it as a randomized function.

More precisely I am trying to lower bound $I(X^n;Y)$ where $Y=\mathcal{A}(X^n)$.

I know that:
$$I(X^n;Y)\geq n(I(X;Y)) $$ and that $0\leq I(X;Y) \leq \log(|\mathcal{X}|)$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are far from independent I would argue that $I(X;Y)>0$. Do you think that it is possible that $I(X^n;Y)$ is not polynomial in $n$? Could it be that $I(X;Y)\approx(1/n)$? Is there something trivial that I am not considering?

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: I suspect you need some constraint on your algorithm, as it is always possible to construct an algorithm for which I(X^n;Y)=0, which necessarily implies that I(X;Y)=0.

Comment: @JohnPolcari, you are totally right. I did not properly formalize it, but ideally I am considering algorithms where this does not happen (more specifically, Learning algorithms)

Comment: I would expect that how you might bound I(X^n;Y) would intimately depend upon how you choose to constrain your algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure $I(X^n;Y) \ge nI(X;Y)$ follows - consider the case $\mathcal{A}(X^n) = X_1.$ Also, you need to be a little less cavalier about writing $I(X;Y)$ - what is $X$? $Y$ is a stochastic function of a sequence $X^n,$ is $X$ one of these? Some independent copy of one of these? This is of course just reiterating John's point, but really at this level of generality basically nothing can be said.